# Download speed via Wi-Fi (phone) faster than LAN (PC)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, android

Here's my speed on PC/LAN

[image]

Here's my speed on phone/Wi-Fi

[image]

Albeit the difference is just 0.10 Mbps, it's been consistently like this for several days during my tests.

During this test, router QoS is disabled. I also tried directly plugging the PC from the modem (bypassing the router), still the same. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: The speed difference is a statistical blimp.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Ramhound A reliably reproducible 10% slowdown is not a "statistical blimp [sic]".

Comment: @IMB Debugging this could easily require full packet captures of each session, and possibly running them through tcptrace looking for potential TCP tuning problems.

Comment: I'd guess you've checked your internet adapter settings on your PC are set to full duplex, 1gbps? (Or whatever the Max through our is for your n/w card).  Do you know when this started happening?  Had you installed any updates or changed anything before the issue started?